# How to match range of numbers excluding first digit

Tags: regex

Could anybody help me to create regular expression which will match range of numbers not including first digit from range. Problem looks something like like this:

`([1-9])` *some other meta characters*  `[\1-9]`

How can I match digit from range not including number stored in `\1`?

EXAMPLE:
I would like to find numbers which match following rule `XZ0XYYXZ000X` where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are numbers between 1 and 9 (`0 < x < Y < Z`).

EXAMPLE2: I have file which contains a lot of lines with some random numbers:

2720337
3730447
1362874
etc.

Now, I want to extract these lines (for example with grep) which match certain criteria (for example numbers `2720337`  and `3730447` match criteria `XZX0YYZ`, where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are numbers between 1 and 9 in following relation `X < Y < Z` and 0 is zero). My catch was something like this `([1-9])([\1-9])\1(0)([\1-\2])\3\2`, but I can not find way to omit greatest and lowest value from range `[\1-\2]` or lowest from `[\1-9]`

Comment: You should give at least one example of input data (more is better), and what part exactly you want to capture. (edit it into your question)

Comment: Please give an example I cannot decode what you're trying to say.

Comment: Can you give a specific input and then the expected output from that specific input?

Comment: I think I understand what you want. But if I understand it correctly, it is quite arcane and a regex is not suited for it.

Comment: **Split the number and do some math.** REGEX isn't suited to compute this: `Find XZ0XYYXZ000X, Where 0 < X < Y < Z`

Comment: Ok, with your second example, I understand it. Definitely no regex. But can you tell me, is it correct that you only have three different digits per number besides 0?  
Would 7270773 also be a valid number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex enforces the uniqueness of `X`, `Y` and `Z`:

```
([1-9])((?!\1)[1-9])\10((?!\1|\2)[1-9])\3\2
```

...but there's no way to enforce their ordering with a regex.

---

About the regex:

`([1-9])` captures the first digit in group #1.  That's the first `X` in your template.

`((?!\1)[1-9])` captures the second digit in group #2, but only after the negative lookahead confirms that it isn't the same as the first digit.  That's the `Z` value.

`\1` matches the third digit, assuming it's the same as the first digit.

`0` is obvious

`((?!\1|\2)[1-9])` represents the `Y` value, so we have to confirm that it's not the same as either of the other two captures.  It's captured in group #3.

`\3` matches the same digit again; that's the second `Y`.

`\2` matches another of whatever the `Z` value was, and Bob's your uncle!

Getting back to that `0` again, there's one caveat that I overlooked.  If there happen to be ten or more capturing groups in the regex, `\10` could be interpreted as a backreference to group #10.  It's a good idea to break up that kind of thing whether it needs it or not.

Many regex flavors provide alternative notation that isolates the group reference, like `\g<1>` or `${1}`.  Not knowing what flavor you're using, I'll use square brackets to isolate the zero instead (i.e., turn it into a single-element character class):

```
([1-9])((?!\1)[1-9])\1[0]((?!\1|\2)[1-9])\3\2
```

Comment: OK, uniqueness of `X`, `Y` and `Z` could be enough, ordering could be done outside... but could you explain more in detail your code, I 'm not familiar with some parts of syntax... I 'm asking this cause I need to implement other sorts of pattern `XYY0ZZY`, `X0Y0ZZZ`, etc. Thanks a lot

Comment: @d3ky: there's your explanation.

Comment: Thanks Alan, this could be solution for my issue. I will perform "ordering" somewhere outside.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're matching a string **XY**, where 0 < **X** < **Y** <= 9.  You can easily extend it to your needs.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use a back-reference in a character class.
The only way I know to make it is by explicitly writing a case for each value of **X**:
`1[2-9]|2[3-9]|3[4-9]|4[5-9]|5[6-9]|6[7-9]|7[89]|89`.

It would be possible (ex. using negative look-ahead) to make sure that **Y** does not equal **X**, as in: `([1-9])(?!\1)[1-9]`, but this does not make sure **Y** is not less than **X**.

Comment: if you could explain how I can distinguish `X`, `Y` and `Z` using structure like you mentioned (`([1-9])(?!\1)[1-9]`) maybe I can do same sorting outside... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's give this a try... finally.
If your second example means the numbers have the same pattern considering their same-digit-at-a-place-properties, you could at least use a regex to first check this:

```
([1-9])([1-9])(\1)0([1-9])\4\2
```

This will match 2720337 and 3730447.

The regex captures some parts. Check, if $1 < $4 and $4 < $2 and you're done. If I understood you correctly, that is.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a lot of different patterns. Your suggestion is OK for this particular pattern `XZX0YYZ`,  but what about for example `XYXYZ0Z`...